# Corrupted Fortran95 read with Multiple Data Type Input

Tags: file-io, io, fortran, fortran95

After extended bug-hunting I've narrowed down that the issue appears to be coming from the input file, but my Professor and I have already tackled that avenue extensively, so the trouble might be my code.

The program (for now) is meant to read lines from a file format supporting multiple data types into a specially formatted array.

To test that functionality, I've made a temporary variable of the required type and printed out the result.

Here is my code:

```
program grading
implicit none
integer :: units = 16
integer :: uniti = 20
integer :: stuNum
character(12) :: fname0, fnam1


TYPE struct1
integer :: stNum
character(31) :: fname, Lname, MI(1)
character(22) :: locat
Integer :: phone
character(1) :: gender
integer :: classLevel
character(4) :: Major
integer :: credits
integer :: cmGPA
ENDTYPE struct1

TYPE(struct1), dimension(2) :: records
print *, "Enter the filename to be read"
read *, fname0

call fopen(units, fname0)
call populateType(units, records)
!***************************************************************

 contains

subroutine fopen(units, fname0)
integer, intent(in) :: units
character(12), intent(in) :: fname0
integer :: test
open(unit=units, file=fname0, status="old", action="read", form = "formatted, iostat=test)
if(test /= 0) STOP "Error opening"
end subroutine fopen
!***************************************************************

subroutine populateType(units, records)
integer, intent(in) :: units
TYPE(struct1), dimension(2), intent(out) :: records
TYPE(struct1) :: store
integer :: test, loop

read (units,*, iostat = test)records
if(test > 0) then
write(*,*) "Something wrong with input"
else if (test < 0) then
write(*,*) "end of file reached"
else
print *, records
read *, records
endif

!read(units, 15, iostat=test)records
!if(test /= 0) stop "error reading"
!print *, records
!read *, records

15 format(I5,A31,A22,I7,A1,I1,A4,I2,I3)
close(units, status="keep")
end subroutine populateType
!***************************************************************
end program grading
```

Whenever I run the unformatted read without the iostat test, I get a bunch of zeros and integers that are inappropriately spaced ("Something wrong with input" when included).

Calling 'more' on the student.dat file to be read produces lines similar to the following:

```
10226FREUD    FRED   ELYNDEN, WASHINGTON     8340115M1PSYC 15185
10110PETERS  ANDREW  JLYNDEN, WASHINGTON     3239550M5ART  63205
10126ARISTOTLE ALICE ACHINO, CALIFORNIA      3330861F3PHIL 78310
10144LUCKY     LUCY  LGRANDVILLE, MICHIGAN   7745424F5HIST 66229
10284ORANGE   DUTCH  VGRAAFSCHAAP, MICHIGAN  3141660M2ENGR 42298
```

Also I'm working with a SMP Debian Linux OS x86_64

Originally we thought the problem was due to remote access corruption from a Mac, but the issue persists even when tested on the local workstations.

Any help figuring how to read without generating garbage values would be appreciated!

Comment: You do a read `read (units,*, iostat = test)records` and on success you do a `print *, store` without any actions to place data in `store`

Comment: Some indentation in the code wouldn't hurt. Looking at the read statement, for the beginning, I would advise not to read by means of the struct1 (variable records) but by means of the individual elements and print the resulting values to see what happens.

Comment: Note that `read (units,*, iostat = test)` is not an unformatted read, it uses the `*` format, which essentially asks the compiler to do its best to interpret what it reads.  Trouble is, it can't understand the first (or any other) line of the input file as a `struct1`.  Best solution ?  Edit the input file to put a `,` between each value on each line.  If that's not possible, then you'll have to use an explicit format to read a line (like the format identified as `15`, but not that one because it doesn't match the input lines).

Comment: It was indeed a formatting issue! Thank you!